# Bank Loan for Father's property

Tags: loans, home

Is it possible for me to acquire a bank loan for purchasing a house from my father if it is not ancestral property?

Comment: Country please.

Comment: This is almost certainly a request about properties in the Indian subcontinent, and with high probability, a property in India where _ancestral property_  is a concept applied to Hindus and possibly to people professing other religions too.